# Merge two list with same elements but different data in a single one with all the data?

Tags: java, arraylist

I had two list:

Entity has Name, Date and Level

```
List<Entity> aList;
List<Entity> bList;
```

Both have the same entities, but one has the name and the date and the other has the name and the level. How can I join in a single list with all the data?

This is what I have, but I was wondering if there are a better way to do this because the lists could be huge

```
aList.parallelStream().forEach(a -> {
            Entity entityWithExtraData = bList.stream().filter(a -> a.getName().equals(b.getName())).findFirst().orElse(null);
            if (entityWithExtraData != null){
                a.setDate(entityWithExtraData.getDate());

            }
        });
```

Comment: Copy bList to a Map with name as key to allow direct lookup?

Comment: Are the lists in the same order? Are the names unique?

Comment: No, the order is not the same. I will try mapping bList. Thanks.